# Issues Looping members in an Async function, Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am new here, and myself and my friend are very stuck with our Discord bot code where we are trying to have my discord bot check if someone is "streaming" to twitch by looping through members that have a Role called "Twitch Streamer". The problem is, we know the first half of the code works which checks if the owner, Me, is streaming, but for some reason, the second half of the code stopped working and is spitting out something in the console of "undefined". If I paste the code, could someone be willing to help us out? We are completely lost and running out of ideas.

Comment: Paste the code here or hastebin if context is long.

Comment: This is the code we're working with.

https://hastebin.com/acomenesuj.js

Comment: What Discord.js version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I had to reedit the code. https://hastebin.com/qifuhenani.js

Answer (score 0):

My approach on task like this would be like this **Discord.js v12 approach**

Filter out the users with specific role - loop iteration decrease - optimization.

```
const streamers = server.members.cache.filter(user => user.roles.cache.has(StreamerRole);
```

To check if `streamer` is currently streaming at a time we are using loop. We are pushing streamers that are streaming to array with their IDs (d.js snowflakes).

```js
const activeStreamers = [];
const IS_STREAMING = new Discord.Activity({
  type: 'STREAMING',
  ...rest
})
streamers.forEach(streamer => {
  const streamerActivity = streamer.presence.activities.has(IS_STREAMING);
  if(streamerActivity) activeStreamers.push(streamer.user.id);
}
```

Comment: We'll try that, and let you know the results. Stay by.

Comment: It's gotten worse, we updated our Discord.js to Version 12 and now our embed isn't even working.
https://pastebin.com/HMm4SThX

Comment: You need to go through JS docs. Also `Activity` class does not provide a constructor so you need to compare it differentely.